# A modified question of Hazay & Lindell's Efficient Secure Two-Party protocols Book

Tags: protocol-design, protocol-analysis, paillier

[image]
Based on the question proposed on page 27, we propose a modified question as follows:

Suppose the protocol is based on Paillier cryptosystem and $P_2$ has generated related public and private keys ($P_2$ publishes its pub key). Then, $P_1$ will encrypt $x$ using the public key and send it to $P_2$.

Considering this scenario, is it secure in the semi-honest model?

Comment: Encryption hides information from someone who doesn't know the decryption key, but $P_2$ knows the key in this case. $P_2$ can obtain $x$ even when its input $y=0$, so the protocol is not semi-honest secure.

Comment: @Mikero Isn't that an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promoting my comment to an answer: Encryption hides information from someone who doesn't know the decryption key. In your case, $P_2$ knows the decryption key, and can therefore learn $x$. This is really no different than sending $x$ in the clear to $P_2$.

Note that this is the strange example from the book that is secure in the malicious setting but not in the semi-honest setting. Adding the encryption step doesn't change that. Your modified protocol leaks $x$ to a semi-honest $P_2$ even when its input is $y=0$, so the protocol is not semi-honest secure. But your modified protocol is secure against malicious $P_2$ since malicious $P_2$ always learns $x$ in the ideal world without loss of generality.